# Import numpy not going good?

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy

When I import numpy it sends a bunch of errors

```
>>> import numpy
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/__init__.py", line 142, in <module>
    from . import core
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/__init__.py", line 59, in <module>
    from . import numeric
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/numeric.py", line 3093, in <module>
    from . import fromnumeric
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/fromnumeric.py", line 17, in <module>
    from . import _methods
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/_methods.py", line 158, in <module>
    _NDARRAY_ARRAY_FUNCTION = mu.ndarray.__array_function__
AttributeError: type object 'numpy.ndarray' has no attribute '__array_function__'
```

Comment: https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/12736

Answer (score -1):

The easiest solution would be to reinstall numpy.

Open command prompt and type:

`pip3 uninstall numpy`

or

`pip uninstall numpy`

for python 2,

then,

`pip install numpy`